# How to iterate over two variables at same time?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

My code looks as follows:

```
startDates = ['2011-01-01','2012-01-01']
endDates = ['2013-01-01','2014-01-01']
theJuice = []

for startDate in startDates and endDate in endDates:
    start_date = startDate 
    end_date = endDate
    print start_date
    print end_date
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Read docs for builtin `zip()` function.

Comment: Do you want every combination of startDate and endDate? That is, do you want 2 iterations or 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip(*iterables)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for startDate, endDate in zip(startDates, endDates):
    print startDate
    print endDate
```

Output:

```
2011-01-01
2013-01-01
2012-01-01
2014-01-01
```

Comment: Not sure what the value is in answering such a consistent duplicate with an inferior answer to the linked dupe.